# Как проверить в строке валидность данных в формате JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, парсер

> Одно решение у меня есть, но не устраивает в силу ряда причин:

```
var cmd='',ldat=0;
cmd='{"ff":"1"}';
function test(){try {return msg(Object.keys(JSON.parse(cmd)).length);} 
      catch (err) {return msg(0);}}

  function msg(s){
      ldat=s;
  };
test(cmd,ldat);
```

я просто смотрю длину объекта, если не меньше одного элемента - то, что то есть на обработку. но как быть с этим:

```
cmd='{"ff":"';
```

или

```
cmd='{""::""}';
```

..?
Подскажите если есть более интересные решения, я пока к сожалению не решил..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function isValidJson(str) {
  try {
    JSON.parse(str);
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    //console.error(e.message);
    return false;
  }
}

var test = [
  '[1,2,3',
  '[1,2,3]',
  '{"ff":"',
  '{"a":"b"}',
  '{""::""}'
];
test.forEach(s => console.log(isValidJson(s)));
```

Или возвращать объект, в случае валидной JSON-строки:

```
function parseValidJson(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Без try/catch - как я понимаю ни как?  Были мысли сделать регулярными выражениями, но больно уж много действий... И выигрыш будет 0-й.. я о скорости.

Comment: @Valery, в принципе, регуляркой можно проверять, но я бы этого не советовал делать хотя бы потому, что шансов на ошибку несоизмеримо больше.

Comment: пока видимо только этот вариант и останется. Но надежду терять не буду. Иногда бывает идея рождается когда уже половину кода сделал... :-)

Comment: @Valery, я не против. Только не забудьте потом поделиться с остальными ;)

Comment: однозначно! .. я не ханжа.. ;-)